# Which weblogic class or jar contains following String "Could not create pool connection for datasource"

Tags: java, weblogic

As part of an RCA, I am trying to find out which class/jar contains this string "Could not create pool connection for datasource", but with no luck.
I tried running following command inside my build directory

To find in classes: 
find  -name "*.class" -type f -print0 -exec grep "Could not create pool connection for datasource" {} \; >output.txt

To find in jars:
 find  -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p | grep -q 'Could not create pool connection for datasource' && echo %p\n" | sh

It cannot happen this class is not present in our build, as I am sure, it is a string which comes from weblogic api.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you care? Anyway, it looks like an exception message, so the stacktrace would tell you exactly which method in which class threw the exception. Then you only need to find which jar contains that class. Then find the source code for that jar to confirm.

Comment: @Andreas it is not showing any relevant trace:                                                     
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'XXXXDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'jdbc/YYYY' weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'YYYY'. The DBMS driver exception was: IO Error: Connection reset

Comment: at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:778)
 at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
 at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784)
 at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756)
 at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)